# Change data in dropdownlist with ajax,jquery mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdownlisftFor that populate some data from the database that is filtered, and a checkbox. The idea is that, when i uncheck the checkbox, I want to change the data, that is populated in the dropdownbox, with the data of the database without the filter.

Which is the good approach to make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested method would be to load your dropdown list as a separate action with a bool parameter of `filtered`. you can call this in your view with `@Html.Action("DropDownList", new {filtered = true})`

Then when you uncheck the check box call a function that replaces the dropdown with the action with unfiltered data.

```
$("#myCheckBox").click(function() {
    if($("#myCheckBox").attr("checked") == "checked"){
        $("#divContainingDropDown").load("../path/to/dropdown/action?filtered=true")
    } else {
        $("#divContainingDropDown").load("../path/to/dropdown/action?filtered=false")
    }
}
```

This function will work for filtering and unfiltering the data in your list.

Comment: That is ok, but the model is empty, when i make the load of the partial view, how i pass the model using load

Comment: Marked, but there is anyway to pass the model using load?

Comment: No, Load does a "get" request so you can pass query string parameters. But don't forget that load is accessing something on the server so you should also have access to the model. If you are after a particular set of data, then pass over some parameters that indicate that. Perhaps you need to update your question with some more source code if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax and jQuery will be easy and better way to do it.

Comment: yes i Know that.i mean how?, i dont know how to make the call to ajax and how to replace then the result into the dropdown